# Can you restrict the PHYSICAL memory a .net program uses and force it to use the page file?

Tags: .net, memory, memory-management

Pretty much what the title says.

I have a memory intensive .net console program (x64) that is not at all time-sensitive. I'd like to be able to force it to use less physical memory in order to keep my OS more responsive for other tasks and run just more quietly in the background (even if this means it takes a lot longer for the console program to complete).

It runs fine just now automatically paging when it needs to but at its most intensive it slows other things down pretty badly.

Is what I am suggesting possible? And, if so, is it advisable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See e.g.:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/clinth/archive/2012/10/11/can-a-process-be-limited-on-how-much-physical-memory-it-uses.aspx
(tools - such as Windows System Resource Manager )

or

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686237(v=vs.85).aspx
(API - SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx function)